# Create many passes from the app - iphone passbook

Tags: ios6, passbook

**SITUATION :**

I have an application where i have to issue a gift cupon kind of a thing when the user reaches a certain score say 'x'.
I want to create a coupon with a unique QRcode, at the time the user reaches the score 'x' so that he can download it on his iphone and use it. Once it is used , the cupon should be invalidated. this applies to any user using the application. Meaning a coupon is created once the score is reached and deleted or invalidated once it is used.

**ISSUE :**

I'm not able to figure out how to create a cupon everytime any user reaches the score. Ofcourse, i did go through a lot of documentations and links like http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1. I also tried using pass-source but the valid account requires you to pay minimum about 8$.

As suggested in raywenderlich tutorials, i can create passes but thats not created through the application.

Also i didn't see any method where we can be notified when a user uses his issued coupon so that we can invalidate it.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Using" a QR code on a coupon means it is scanned by something else. That something else has to take responsibility to report the activity back to you, so you could then update the pass with an "Expired" flag in your database, re-sign and rebuild the pass, issue the push notification so that it would eventually update on the device. You'd also probably want that scanner-thingie to check with you to see that the code is valid before accepting it. So, yeah, not Apple's problem.

Comment: so i have to take the refuge or something like pass source is what you are telling rite?

Comment: You said the QR code is "used". If that means scanning, then because the pass/iPhone is completely passive in that process the scanner software/hardware system must somehow communicate with the software system you used to create the pass.

Comment: im aware of that.. that's y i wanted to know whether the framework has any apis for the notification.. this applies to even passsource or passkit